# Are there cartesian closed monads that also preserve the closed structure of the CCC

Tags: monads, cartesian-closed-categories

When I look for cartesian closed monads, I only find monads where the endofunctor preserves the cartesian structure of a cartesian closed category

$$
\operatorname T\ (a \times b) = (\operatorname T\ a) \times (\operatorname T\ b).
$$

Are there any monads that also preserve the closed structure of a cartesian closed category, so that

$$
\operatorname T\ (a^b) = (\operatorname T\ a) ^{\operatorname T\ b},
$$

where $a^b$ denotes the exponential object of $a$ and $b$ in the category?

Comment: I don't have time to give a detailed answer now, but Kock's [Bilinearity and Cartesian closed monads](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24491025) may be relevant to you.